# Why does my C# Winforms program with a timer get bogged down after a day?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, timer

I have a program that updates two DataGridView objects every minute with a MySQL query from our internal orders database so we can keep track of older orders and make sure they're being handled.

It works well, but if you leave the program on it starts to get slower and slower and you really notice it after a day or so. Restarting the program fixes this, but I'd really like to know why I can't just leave this running.

Here is the timer code and the function it calls:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateOrderDisplay();
    }

        private void UpdateOrderDisplay()
    {
        grdOrderItems.Rows.Clear();
        grdHoldOrders.Rows.Clear();
        string strsql;
        string CustomerName;
        string MyConString = "SERVER=**********;" + "DATABASE=***********;" + "UID=************;" + "PASSWORD=***********;";
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
        {
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            strsql = "select * from orders where ship_reference=0 and OnHold =0 order by order_id asc";
            command.CommandText = strsql;
            connection.Open(); Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                if (Reader["payment_date"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    if (Reader["custom"].ToString().Contains("~*"))
                    {
                        CustomerName = Reader["custom"].ToString().Substring(0, Reader["custom"].ToString().IndexOf("~"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CustomerName = Reader["shipping_address_name"].ToString();
                    }
                    grdOrderItems.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => grdOrderItems.Rows.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["payment_date"].ToString().Substring(0, 21)).ToString(), Reader["txn_id"].ToString(), CustomerName, Reader["mc_gross"].ToString(), Reader["memo"].ToString(), Reader["order_id"].ToString())));
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            strsql = "select * from orders where OnHold =1 order by order_id asc";
            command.CommandText = strsql;
            connection.Open(); Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                if (Reader["payment_date"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    if (Reader["custom"].ToString().Contains("~*"))
                    {
                        CustomerName = Reader["custom"].ToString().Substring(0, Reader["custom"].ToString().IndexOf("~"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CustomerName = Reader["shipping_address_name"].ToString();
                    }
                    grdHoldOrders.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => grdHoldOrders.Rows.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(Reader["payment_date"].ToString().Substring(0, 21)).ToString(), Reader["txn_id"].ToString(), CustomerName, Reader["mc_gross"].ToString(), Reader["memo"].ToString(), Reader["order_id"].ToString(),Reader["Hold_Review_Date"].ToString().Substring(0,Reader["Hold_Review_Date"].ToString().IndexOf(" ")),Reader["payer_email"].ToString())));
                }
            }





            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Also, in case it's relevant, here is some code I use to color code the lines of the DataGridView object so we can easily tell which order is older:

```
    private void grdOrderItems_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        grdOrderItems.RowPrePaint += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventHandler(this.grdOrderItems1_RowPrePaint);

    }
    private void grdOrderItems1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex <= grdOrderItems.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            string StringNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            string NowTime = StringNow.Substring(StringNow.IndexOf(" ")+1, StringNow.Length- StringNow.IndexOf(" ")-1);
            string OrderDateTime = grdOrderItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, grdOrderItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString().IndexOf(" ")+1) + NowTime;
            if ((Convert.ToDateTime(StringNow) - Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDateTime)).Days > 2)
            {
                grdOrderItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((Convert.ToDateTime(StringNow) - Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDateTime)).Days > 1)
                {
                    grdOrderItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((Convert.ToDateTime(StringNow) - Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDateTime)).Days > 0)
                    {
                        grdOrderItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tan;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dispose those `Command`s.

Comment: Yeah, close the reader explicitly after use (or put it in a `using`), would be my first thing to change.

Comment: Is the `grdOrderItems_RowPrePaint` an actual live handler that also fires? If so, you are adding another subscriber to `grdOrderItems.RowPrePaint` each time it fires, and after a while each `grdOrderItems.RowPrePaint` will cause thousands of executions of `this.grdOrderItems1_RowPrePaint`.

Comment: @GSerg The command is actually only one that is being reused. Also it's declared locally and will cease to exist once the execution runs out of its scope (which is the using block).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Also, I'd avoid closing and reopening the connection between queries. Close only the reader instead.

Comment: @GSerg Good eye. I did notice something weird on using the event to add a handler to the same event, but I still didn't think of that.

Comment: @MatheusRocha It's fine to reuse your local variable inside the routine if you dispose it in the end. Nobody says the connection should be closed between commands either, only that it should be disposed in the end. You should probably consult reference on garbage collection and why it may not happen for a very long time.

Comment: @GSerg I know. That was my point. What I said was that it was more than one command, just one that he reused. And that since it's local there is no need to dispose of it, as it will be done once the code runs out of scope.

Comment: @MatheusRocha No it won't. It will continue to exist until collected by the garbage collector, which may not happen in a while. That is precisely the reason why `IDisposable` exists.

Comment: Thanks all! I'll change these things and give it a try.

Comment: @GSerg You're right.

Comment: You don't need to close and re-open the connection in between the two commands.

Comment: Also, how big can the "custom" text be? How many fields are in the `orders` table, and do you really need to `select *`?

Comment: Oh, and you can get `NowTime` like this: `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")`

Comment: Thanks everyone! I realized it was silly to use the RowPrePaint event to color the DataGridView rows when I'm rebuilding the grid anyway, so I just added the coloring to the UpdateOrderDisplay function (using the suggested code from @JoelCoehoorn below). I've also closed out the Reader. Next I'm going to restrict the fields returned by MySQL to only the ones I actually need because there can be some large fields in there. Hopefully between all of these changes it gets better!

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a  MySqlDataReader leak. When you're done with each `Reader` object, dispose of it. This is a good way to make that happen; it's resilient against exceptions, and the `reader` variable goes out of scope at the end of the using.

```
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           /* your per-row logic here */
        }
    }
```

You can also do this with Close():

```
    MySqlDataReader Reader; 
      ...
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
       /* your per-row logic here */
    }
    Reader.Close();
```

You are closing and reopening the Connection for each query. That's not necessary. Open it once, use it for both queries, and then close it.

You might consider keeping your Connection open for longer than a single timer tick. (If you have a connection pool, ignore this advice.)

Use the Task Manager to see how much cpu% and memory your program takes up (in the morning and again in the evening).  If the memory is growing, you have some kind of leak. If the cpu% is growing, you have some sort of list processing going on where the list gets longer with every tick.

Comment: For the last, it depends on the tick length, and a full minute connection pooling means he probably really does want a new connection object with each tick. In my experience, anything more than a few seconds idle and it's best to let the prior connection object dispose. But you're right that he should be able to re-use a single connection for the whole tick even handler method.

Comment: A red note on the `RowPrePaint` event that adds a new handler (`grdOrderItems.RowPrePaint += new (...)`) each time is raised. That's going to kill everything. I'm surprised it goes on a whole day.

Comment: @Jimi You should add that as an answer. I missed that first time through, but it's definitely a factor, if not the entire problem.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn  It would be interesting to ask the OP whether this is some kind of *style* and it's, possibly, applied elsewhere. Anyway, there are already two answers to this question and, now I see, a bunch of comments that point this out. You two should pick it up, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough info for a complete answer, except to say this smells like a large object heap issue, where one of the fields you retrieve from the database will occasionally be longer than the 85K LOH threshold.

What I can do, and it might even help, is show you how to *greatly* simplify and improve the prepaint method like this:

```
private void grdOrderItems1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > grdOrderItems.Rows.Count - 1) return;
    var row = grdOrderItems.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    TimeSpan timeOfDay = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today;
    //It *looks like* Cells[0].Value is already a DateTime, but I'm not 100% on this
    // If I'm wrong and it's a string, its worth it to parse just that one value to a DateTime here, and still plug that DateTime value into this code instead of the Cell.
    DateTime OrderDateTime = ((DateTime)row.Cells[0].Value).Date + timeOfDay;

    var days = (DateTime.Now - OrderDateTime).TotalDays;
    if (days > 2)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
    }
    else if (days > 1)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (days > 0)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tan;
    }
}
```

This reduces nesting and extra blocks, making it a lot easier to understand, and it probably runs in less than half the time because of the reduced back-and-forth between string and DateTime values. The cultural/internationalization issues make converting between DateTime and string in either direction an inherently slow and error-prone operation.